# Remove a given value from a string along with comma in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove a set of given values from a string of comma separated values as follows:

```
// mainString

mainString = '1,2,3,4,5'

// Values to subtracted from mainString

givenValuesString1 = '1'

givenValuesString2 = '2,3'

givenValuesString3 = '5'

givenValuesString4 = '3,5'

// Desired Output Values

desiredOutput1 = '2,3,4,5'

desiredOutput2 = '1,4,5'

desiredOutput3 = '1,2,3,4'

desiredOutput4 = '1,2,4'
```

What I tried is this:

```
desiredOutput =  mainString.replace(givenValuesString, '')

desiredOutput =  mainString.replace(`${givenValuesString},`, '')
```

My problem is that when I try the second method, value without a comma after it is not deleted i.e., the last character in the mainString. Another problem is I am not able to delete the values if they are one after another i.e, values like `2,4` or `3,5`.

Values remaining if I use the above two methods:

```
// First method

desiredOutput1 = ',2,3,4,5'

desiredOutput2 = '1,,4,5'

desiredOutput3 = '1,2,3,4,'

desiredOutput4 = '1,2,3,4,5'

// Second method

desiredOutput1 = '2,3,4,5'

desiredOutput2 = '1,4,5'

desiredOutput3 = '1,2,3,4,5'

desiredOutput4 = '1,2,3,4,5'
```

So how can I achieve the desired result? i.e., the given values along with the comma must be deleted from the mainString and also even if they are not adjacent to each other.

Comment: use string.split() function

Comment: do you need to keep the order? Is the input string always increasing? (therefore the result is always increasing?)

Comment: Order does not matter. Input string is always the same on page load. Only the values to be removed change.

Comment: All answers worked for me. I am going to upvote all answers and select the first answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```js
const mainString = "1,2,3,4,5";

const givenValuesString1 = "1";
const givenValuesString2 = "2,3";
const givenValuesString3 = "5";
const givenValuesString4 = "3,5";

const removeFromCsv = (values, filterValues) =>
  values
    .split(",")
    .filter(v => !filterValues.split(",").includes(v))
    .join(",");

console.log(
  removeFromCsv(mainString, givenValuesString1), // 2,3,4,5
  "-",
  removeFromCsv(mainString, givenValuesString2), // 1,4,5
  "-",
  removeFromCsv(mainString, givenValuesString3), // 1,2,3,4
  "-",
  removeFromCsv(mainString, givenValuesString4) // 1,2,4
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `Map` or `Set` to do it.
If you want order, then `Map`.
Otherwise `Set`. Since you mentioned you don't need the order, I have used `Set` to do it.

```js
mainString = '1,2,3,4,5'

givenValuesString1 = '1'
givenValuesString2 = '2,3'
givenValuesString3 = '5'
givenValuesString4 = '3,5'

function subtract(main, s) {
  let set = new Set(main.split(",").map(a => Number(a)));
  s.split(",").map(a => Number(a)).forEach(a => set.delete(a))
  return Array.from(set).join(",")
}

console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString1));
console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString2));
console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString3));
console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString4));
```

Actually, even if using `Set`, if you don't do a `set1 - set2` kind of operation, you can keep the order:

```js
mainString = '1,2,3,4,5'

givenValuesString1 = '1'
givenValuesString2 = '2,3'
givenValuesString3 = '5'
givenValuesString4 = '3,5'

function subtract(main, s) {
  let set = new Set(s.split(",").map(a => Number(a)));
  return main.split(",").filter(a => !set.has(Number(a))).join(",")
}

console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString1));
console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString2));
console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString3));
console.log(subtract(mainString, givenValuesString4));
```

In general, you'd avoid any method that uses O(n²) time complexity (the ones above are not).  That's because if the main string is 1,000,000 entries and the "removal" string is 500,000 entries, you'd be look at 1,000,000 x 500,000 = 500,000,000,000 steps (roughly speaking, in that order of magnitude).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var mainString = "1,2,3,4,5";
var givenString ="2,3";

var strarr = mainString.split(",");
var givarr = givenString.split(",");

var output = strarr.filter(function(val){
    return !givarr.includes(val);
});

var desiredOutput = output.join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string.split() function to convert your string to array, then iterate to remove the elements, then use array.join() function to convert the resulting array back to string.

```js
// mainString

var mainString = '1,2,3,4,5'

// Values to subtracted from mainString

var givenValuesString1 = '1'

var givenValuesString2 = '2,3'

var givenValuesString3 = '5'

var givenValuesString4 = '3,5'

// Desired Output Values

var desiredOutput1 = '2,3,4,5'

var desiredOutput2 = '1,4,5'

var desiredOutput3 = '1,2,3,4'

var desiredOutput4 = '1,2,4'




var arr1 = mainString.split(",")
console.log("arr1")
console.log(arr1)

var arrToBeDeleted1 = givenValuesString1.split(",")
console.log("arrToBeDeleted1")
console.log(arrToBeDeleted1)

var arrOutput1 = arr1.slice() // copy the array
console.log("arrOutput1")
console.log(arrOutput1)

for(var i = 0; i < arrToBeDeleted1.length; i++) {
  var toBeDeleted1 = arrToBeDeleted1[i]
  var index1 = arr1.indexOf(toBeDeleted1)
  console.log("index1")
  console.log(index1)
  
  arrOutput1.splice(index1, 1)
  console.log("arrOutput1")
  console.log(arrOutput1)
}

console.log(arrOutput1.join(","))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by using string .split() and by filtering the array.

Here is the code :

```js
function processStr(data){
  var mainStr = "1,2,3,4,5"
  var arrStr = mainStr.split(',')
  
  var filteredArr = arrStr.filter(function(obj) { return data.indexOf(obj) == -1; });
  
  var result = filteredArr.toString();
  
  return result
}

var str1 = processStr('1,2,3')
var str2 = processStr('1')
var str3 = processStr('2,3')
var str4 = processStr('1,4')
console.log(str1)
console.log(str2)
console.log(str3)
console.log(str4)
```

Let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

in your case you have **2 input parameters**:

1. main string like '1,2,3,4,5'
2. blacklist like '2,4'

and you want a string as a result that include main string numbers without numbers in blacklist
see, explain is easier.

so I offer this way :

```
// first define your variables
let main = '1,2,3,4,5';
let blacklist = '3,4';

// now let's make result
let result = main
            .split(',') // split function make an array from your string with delimiter coma => [1,2,3,4,5]
            .filter( // filter function is a simple loop that decrease array with your condition
                 item => blacklist.indexOf(item)==-1 // if current item is in black list ignore it
            )
            .join (','); // and finaly join array elements with coma to make result as string

console.log(result); //tada , it is what you need => '1,2,5'
```